# Changing allowsCellularAccess on existing NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Is it possible to change the value for `allowsCellularAccess` on an existing `NSURLSession` by modifying the underlying `NSURLSessionConfiguration`?

I want to honor any changes in a user's settings for my application without cancelling existing requests if their device is currently connected to WiFi.

Answer (score 7):

No.  A session copies its configuration.  It does not retain it.  What I would do in your situation is:

- Make a copy of the session's existing configuration and change that flag.
- Create a new session with the modified configuration.
- If the user is on Wi-Fi, call finishTasksAndInvalidate on the old session.  This will keep the session around long enough to finish any existing requests, after which it will go away.
- If the user is on cellular, call invalidateAndCancel, then wait to restart those tasks until the user is on Wi-Fi.

Additionally, you may be able to call `cancelByProducingResumeData:` on a task, and then recreate (resume) it in a different session with a different configuration.  The task will still report its original configuration for `allowsCellularAccess`, but will behave according to the configuration of the new session.  (The stale reporting might be considered a bug.)

Comment: So if a user starts a download with allowsCellularAccess = NO and then walks outside, realizes the download has stopped, and wants to download over cellular, they will have to start the download all over again?

Comment: If the app uses a download task and if both the app and the server properly support resuming downloads, the user should be able to resume where he or she left off after the device is back on a Wi-Fi network.  However, I'm not aware of any way to make it work in a way that would let you resume over cellular unless `allowsCellularAccess` is `YES` to begin with, because there's no way to move a task to a new session, and no way to modify the `allowsCellularAccess` property of the task's underlying `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: I recently learned that you can actually cancel a task producing resume data and then recreate it in another session.  For some reason, I thought that didn't work, but apparently, I was mistaken.  So that would be a way to change a task's behavior after the fact.